# Prove existance of linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L$ be a linear space and $\dim(L) = n$. Let $K$ be a linear subspace of $L$.

How would you prove, that a linear mapping $l:L\to L$, such that Image of $l$ equals K, does exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: start by choosing a base for $K$, and extend it to a base of $L$. Now try and define the mapping on the latter base.

Comment: I wrote bases, but I don't know how to use them to express the linear mapping

Comment: may I just say, that it is a linear mapping, that transfers bases $b_{s+1}-b_n$ to zero vector? (if $\dim(K) = s$)

Comment: @user50222, yes, and then you have to define the mapping on $b_1, \dots, b_s$.